# How to use a dynamic smarty variable in foreach loop

Tags: variables, dynamic, smarty

Can anyone tell me how to use dynamic variables in smarty foreach loop. I am trying to create a module in prestashop and m very close to get it done.
here's my code:

---

```
//file name index.php
foreach( $subCategories as $s )
{
    $foo  = intval($s['id_category']);
    $k    = new Category($foo);
    $var1 = "subSubCategories.$foo";
    $var1 = $k->getSubCategories(1); 

    $smarty->assign(array('foo'.$foo => $var1)); 
}
```

---

```
//file name:index.tpl

{assign var=foo value=$foo$cat}

//where $cat is a variable that counts the number of categories

{if isset($foo) AND $foo}
    {foreach from=$foo item=subCategories name=homesubCategories}
        <p>{$subCategories.name}</p>
    {/foreach}
{else}
    <p>{l s='test failed'}</p>
{/if}
```

---

I've exhausted all of my resources and knowledge and feeling quite helpless at this moment. so plz help me out.

---

I am trying to create dynamic variables (`'foo'.$foo` i.e. `foo1`, `foo2`, and so on) depending on the number of sub-categories. I think m successful up to this point. Now moving on to the tpl file, here I want to access the dynamically created variable (`foo2`, `foo3` etc.) using foreach. Now if I am doing this: `{assign var=foo value=$foo3}` I succeed in fetching the values from this subcategory using the same foreach loop. But when I do this: `{assign var=foo value=$foo$catx}` (where `$catx` stores the values for category id) it fails. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I use such code in section loop (for **Smarty 2**):

```
{section  name=buildings loop=7 start=1 step=1 max=7}
<tr>
      {assign var=part_number value="part`$smarty.section.buildings.index`_number"}
      <td class="number">
        <input class="number xshort" name="part{$smarty.section.buildings.index}_number" value="{$data.$part_number}" type="text">
      </td>
</tr>
{/section}
```

As you can see, there are a creation of dynamic variable **part_number** (see *backticks* in value block). And then, you can use it as value="{$data.$part_number}".

Answer (score 0):

With `$foo = intval($s['id_category']);` you defined `$foo` as an integer.
Then you concat the string with `$smarty->assign(array('foo'.**$foo** => $var1));`

Correct is:

```
$foo = $s['id_category'];
$smarty->assign(array('foo'.$foo => $var1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but it does not seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$smarty->assign()` call is incorrect; you've only got one parameter being sent to it, but it [needs two parameters](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl#language.assigned.variables) (the variable name, followed by the value). Based on your template code (looping through variable `$foo`), your loop should be something like this in PHP:

```
//file name index.php
$subcats = array();
foreach($subCategories as $s) {
    $foo = intval($s['id_category']);
    $k = new Category($foo);    
    $subcats[$foo] => $k->getSubCategories(1);
}
$smarty->assign('foo', $subcats);
```

Then it also looks like you're not using the Smarty `{foreach}` quite properly either. You're declaring the `name` attribute, of the foreach loop, but then not using it properly. Assuming `$k->getSubCategories(1)` returns a string, the smarty code would just have to be:

```
{foreach from=$foo item=subCategories}<p>{$subCategories}</p>{/foreach}
```

If `$k->getSubCategories(1)` returns an array with a 'homesubCategories' element (which is what I think you're trying to get at with your Smarty code), you still don't need the 'name' value on the foreach. You'd then just do:

```
{foreach from=$foo item=subCategories}<p>{$subCategories.homesubCategories}</p>{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to create dynamic variables ('foo'.$foo i.e. foo1, foo2, and so on) depending on the number of sub-categories. I think m successful up to this point. now moving on to the tpl file, here i want to access the dynamically created variable (foo2, foo3 etc) using foreach. now if i am doing this: {assign var=foo value=$foo3} 
i succeed in fetching the values from this subcategory using the same foreach loop. but wen i do this:{assign var=foo value=$foo$catx} (where $catx stores the values for category id)
It FAILS. Plz Help

Comment: Try surrounding the variables in the "value" assignment in double-quotes, and backtick each variable inside it? (http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl)

Comment: Or, re-think your data design, and have the subcategories as sub-elements in an array (accessed by their ID number), rather than a concatenated variable name ("dynamic variables", as you put it), which would be a more streamlined data design.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically named variables are generally a very bad design choice, making everything much more difficult than it needs to be.

If you have a set of elements you need to loop over or index into, put them in an array; then you don't need to do any magic assignments, as you can use normal `foreach` loops or array key access:

```
//file name index.php

// Build the array first, then assign it to Smarty at the end
$foo_array = array();
foreach($subCategories as $s)
{
    $foo = intval($s['id_category']);
    $k = new Category($foo);

    // This line is redundant as you over-write on the following line:
    // $var1 = "subSubCategories.$foo";

    $var1 = $k->getSubCategories(1);
    $foo_array[ $foo ] = $var1;
}
// Assigning one variable, so just pass name and value to $smarty->assign()
$smarty->assign('foo_array', $foo_array);
```

---

```
//file name:index.tpl
{* Look for the entry in the outer array with key "$cat", then loop over it *}
{foreach from=$foo_array[$cat] item=subCategories}
    <p>{$subCategories.name}</p>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to call variable dynamically created in template with this statement:

if for example `$index = 2`

```
{$foo{$index}}
```

then this will call variable with name `{$foo2}`